# Drop first element of hierarchical index in a pandas series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

After a groupby of a pandas dataframe I get the following series:

```
client      Date       Amount
0000000001  date1      val1
            date2      val2
            date3      val3
            date4      val4
            date5      val5
0000000002  date2      val6
            date4      val7
0000000003  date1      val8
            date2      val9
0000000004  date2      val10
            date3      val11
            date4      val12
            date5      val13
```

The question is, how could I get the first entry for each client removed? That is:

```
0000000001  date2      val2
            date3      val3
            date4      val4
            date5      val5
0000000002  date4      val7
0000000003  date2      val9
0000000004  date3      val11
            date4      val12
            date5      val13
```

I fear the question is trivial and is related to hierarchical indices, but I cannot solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated()]
print (df1)
                 Amount
client     Date        
0000000001 date2   val2
           date3   val3
           date4   val4
           date5   val5
0000000002 date4   val7
0000000003 date2   val9
0000000004 date3  val11
           date4  val12
           date5  val13
```

**Details**:

First get values of first level by [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
print (df.index.get_level_values(0))
Index(['0000000001', '0000000001', '0000000001', '0000000001', '0000000001',
       '0000000002', '0000000002', '0000000003', '0000000003', '0000000004',
       '0000000004', '0000000004', '0000000004'],
      dtype='object', name='client')
```

And then return all values without first by [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.duplicated.html):

```
print (df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated())
[False  True  True  True  True False  True False  True False  True  True
  True]
```

If possible duplicated `groups`:

```
print (df)
                 Amount
client     Date        
0000000001 date1   val1
           date2   val2
           date3   val3
           date4   val4
           date5   val5
0000000002 date2   val6
           date4   val7
0000000003 date1   val8
           date2   val9
0000000001 date2  val10
           date3  val11
           date4  val12
           date5  val13

s = df.index.get_level_values(0).to_series()
df1 = df[s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum().duplicated().values]
print (df1)
                 Amount
client     Date        
0000000001 date2   val2
           date3   val3
           date4   val4
           date5   val5
0000000002 date4   val7
0000000003 date2   val9
0000000001 date3  val11
           date4  val12
           date5  val13
```

**Detail**:

```
print (s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum())
client
0000000001    1
0000000001    1
0000000001    1
0000000001    1
0000000001    1
0000000002    2
0000000002    2
0000000003    3
0000000003    3
0000000001    4
0000000001    4
0000000001    4
0000000001    4
Name: client, dtype: int32
```